# Different initialization of base class attribute

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Consider a base class that has an attribute

```
class Base 
{
  protected:

  AttributeBase * elementPtr;
  ...
};
```

And a derived class

```
class Derived : public Base
{
  ...
};
```

Also I have a class `AttributeDerived` which derives from `AttributeBase`

When I create an object of the class `Base` I would like `elementPtr` to be initialized in this way:

```
elementPtr = new AttributeBase()
```

But when I create an object of the class `Derived` I would like `elementPtr` to be initialized in this way:

```
elementPtr = new AttributeDerived()
```

What is the cleanest way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a `protected` constructor to `Base` which allows the derived class to pass an `elementPtr` to use:

```
Base (AttributeBase* elementPtr) : elementPtr(elementPtr)
{}
```

Then in your derived class, call that constructor:

```
Derived() : Base(new AttributeDerived())
{}
```

If you use C++11, you could then have other `Base` constructors delegate to the protected one to limit code duplication.

Answer (score 4):

You could add different ctors of `Base` for different purpose:

```
class Base 
{
  protected:

    AttributeBase * elementPtr;
    Base(AttributeBase * p) : elementPtr(p) {}

  public:
    Base() : elementPtr(new AttributeBase) {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    Derived() : Base(new AttributeDerived) {}
};
```

And then

```
Base b;    // elementPtr = new AttributeBase()
Derived d; // elementPtr = new AttributeDerived()
```